# Understanding calling Parameters in other Activity

Tags: android, parameters, android-intent

Example problem (for understanding)

1. Calculate:

   ```
                x = a + b.
                y = x + c.
   ```
2. Create a method to save the values ​​of x and y to be sent to another Activity.
3. Calling the values ​​of x and y in the other activity in a TextView.

Detailing as much as possible please, I'm starting now and I'm trying to understand. thank you

**Detailing is possible to create variables, like calling them, the types of variables, intent to create ....**

Comment: What have you tried and where have you looked?..What don't you understand about android intents and bundles? if the answer is everything then you should start with documentation and move on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FirstActivity:

```
static public final String A = "a";
static public final String B = "b";

int a = ...
int b = ...
final Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra(A, a);
i.putExtra(B, b);
this.startActivity(i);
```

In the SecondActivity's onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ...
        final Intent startingIntent = this.getIntent();
        final Bundle extras = startingIntent.getExtras();
        a = extras.getInt(FirstActivity.A);
        b = extras.getInt(FirstActivity.B);
...
}
```